# Is there a way to automate PDF reports in Grass GIS through the web?

Tags: grass-gis, pdf, geoprocessing-service, pywps, wpsclient

I am an experienced programmer, but new to GIS. My question: I would like to automate the creation of PDF reports from a website, using Grass GIS.

I've come across Web Processing Service (WPS) (http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wps/) but am unsure how this fits into any possible report automation.

**Is WPS the way to automate report generation, or is some kind of direct scripting (such as with Python) a better solution?**

Comment: I think it depends on how the reports are being used. Are they generated and then served back to the web? Are they remaining on the server?

Comment: We would want the report generated and then served back to the web (so the user can download and save the report).

Comment: I don't think WPS is "the" (as in "the only") way to automate report generation. The main reason I think you would use WPS is if your server side environment is specifically tailored for it (see here for an example using Geoserver: http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/wps/wps.html). I think the best solution is the one that you can execute. Certainly python (ie. reportlab) is a viable option.

Comment: Thank you @rumski20 - theoretically, if I have a predefined report in Grass, using Python (or some other scripting language) would I be able to pass in some parameters from the website, then have Grass process and generate the PDF, which then serves it serves it back from the web?

Comment: Sorry. Can't help you there. I'm not familiar with GRASS GIS. Hopefully somebody here can instruct you in that, however.

Answer (score 1):

Making use of WPS is certainly not the only way of achieving this, but it might simplify a number of things. [PyWPS](http://www.pywps.org) in particular, greatly facilitates the interaction with the GRASS API.

The [pywps-demo](https://github.com/geopython/pywps-demo) project includes an example performing a [buffer with GRASS](https://github.com/geopython/pywps-demo/blob/master/processes/grassbuffer.py), where you can get a good idea of how to wire your process.

In your case, you can define a number of Literal inputs for the report parameters and then a Complex output for the report itself. E.g.:

```
def __init__(self):

        inputs  = [LiteralInput('paramA', 'Parameter A', data_type='float'), 
                   LiteralInput('paramB', 'Parameter B', data_type='string')]

        outputs = [ComplexOutput('report', 'Report',
                   supported_formats=[Format('application/pdf')])]
```